# Get access to all settings for my email account setting in Outlook 365 (SMTP FROM address)

Tags: email, office365, imap, smtp

I have an email address from my church administrator@my-church-url.de.

This emails are forwarded to a private mail address. churchadmin@my-private-url.de.

In my Outlook 365 I can create an IMAP account to churchadmin@my-private-url.de without problem. But I can only set the reply/answer address. I can't see settings to modify my SMTP FROM header to administrator@my-church-url.de. When I send a email, there is still my private email in the header.

The configuration for the email account in Outlook 365 doesn't allow me to create an account under administrator@my-church-url.de. I can change the server addresses for IMAP and SMTP and can give the correct password, but I am not able to change the user name.

Only way is currently to set a reply address.

Is there any way to do it all on my own, like in previous Office versions?

Answer (score 0):

I found no way to change the settings of the From address in a dialog.#
But it is possible to change it via the registry

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Profiles\Outlook<Number of profile><Number of account>

There is a entry Email. Here I found the old (unwanted) email address entered from the wizard. churchadmin@my-private-url.de

I changed it to my the address I wanted administrator@my-church-url.de.

Restart Outlook and done.